# invalid command name "Module/MMac/ALOHA" error ns-2 NS-MIRACLE

Tags: tcl, ns2

I am very new to ns-2 and NS-MIRACLE.

I want to use multiple radio, multiple channel simulation in ns-2. So, I am using NS-MIRACLE Library to do so. But when compiling their samples I got a error. Something like "invalid command name "Module/MMac/ALOHA" error".

I am putting up my console.

```
invalid command name "Module/MMac/ALOHA"
    while executing
"Module/MMac/ALOHA create _o17 "
    invoked from within
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
delete $o
return ""
}
global errorInfo
error "class $..."
    (procedure "new" line 3)
    invoked from within
"new Module/MMac/ALOHA"
    (procedure "createNode" line 8)
    invoked from within
"createNode 1"
    (file "bpsk_aloha.tcl" line 160)
```

The real problem is my ns-miracle can not find the "libmmac.so" library. But when i searched the lib folder it was there.

```
couldn't load file "libmmac.so": /home/mazhar/ns/lib/libmmac.so: undefined symbol: CLMSG_PHY2MAC_ENDTX
    while executing
"load libmmac.so"
    (file "bpsk_aloha.tcl" line 54)
```

So the problem is now that

> undefined symbol: CLMSG_PHY2MAC_ENDTX

Comment: As it says, the command `Module/MMac/ALOHA` doesn't exist. I believe the code is assuming that it is an _existing_ OTcl class. Have you defined it before the point where you call `createNode`?

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I am googling but can't find a way to define the MAC protocol Libraries. Or even don't know whether my code can access those libraries.

Comment: Thanks I have loaded the library. but problem is ns-2 can't access them. I have updated the problem.

Comment: How exactly did you find out that the problem was the missing libmmac.so ? I am facing a similar problem with a custom protocol that I defined and console errors give no clue as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your updated question, you have a library that has not been linked against all its dependencies. That makes it ... *difficult* to use at best. What you should do is find out what library (or libraries) are missing, and add those in during the step where you link the shared library.  Minimally, they will include the symbol `CLMSG_PHY2MAC_ENDTX`, but may have many more. Also watch out for unexpected warnings during the compile step; they can often indicate some much more serious problem.

For the details of how to build shared libs on your platform, search here on Stack Overflow. It is a problem that has been answered many times...